# I need authorization signature code for file download from Blob Storage .Using Rest API

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

My Authentication code is i thing i might be wrong.
I attached my code please refer

> private const string FileDownloadURL =
>   "https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/{1}/{2}";

```
 public async Task<string> DownloaDFileToBlob(string blobname, string downloadpath, string filename)
        {

            string Requesturl = string.Format(FileDownloadURL, storageAccount, blobname, filename);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Requesturl);
            string now = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R");
            string exp = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1).ToString("R");
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2015-12-11");
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", now);
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob");
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", AuthorizationHeader3(now, exp,storageAccount, blobname, filename));
            var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

            using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                return resp.StatusCode.ToString();
            }

        }
```

> My Authentication Header add method

```
private string AuthorizationHeader3(string method, string now, HttpWebRequest request, string storageAccount, string storageKey, string containerName,string filename)
        {

            string headerResource = $"x-ms-date:{now}\nx-ms-version:2015-12-11";
            string canonicalizedResource = $"/{storageAccount}/{containerName}/{filename}\ncomp:metadata\nrestype:container\ntimeout:20";
            var contentEncoding = "";
            var contentLanguage = "";
            var contentLength = "";
            var contentMd5 = "";
            var contentType = "";
            var date = "";
            var ifModifiedSince = "";
            var ifMatch = "";
            var ifNoneMatch = "";
            var ifUnmodifiedSince = "";
            var range = "";
            var stringToSign = $"{method}\n{contentEncoding}\n{contentLanguage}\n{contentLength}\n{contentMd5}\n{contentType}\n{date}\n{ifModifiedSince}\n{ifMatch}\n{ifNoneMatch}\n{ifUnmodifiedSince}\n{range}\n{headerResource}\n{canonicalizedResource}";
            var signature = "";
            using (var hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(storageKey)))
            {
                var dataToHmac = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign);
                signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
            }
            String AuthorizationHeader = String.Format("{0} {1}:{2}", "SharedKey", storageAccount, signature);
            return AuthorizationHeader;
        }
```

Comment: You could just use the Storage SDK: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/.

Comment: @juunas but i need rest API . That ,s why i am asking

Comment: Which feature are you trying to use in the REST API that is not supported by the SDK?

Comment: @juunas All features are support in SDK. but My application is in .net 4.0 version. SDK Support only  .net 4.5.2 version . that ,s why i am using httpclient rest api

Comment: Ahh totally understandable then.

Comment: @juunas ok. I already write code for Get List of files in my blob. Now i need Download API Code, So i attached my sample and authentication3 method for generate signature. I thing some mistakes are there ... :)

Comment: You can check how the SDK does the signing here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/Common/Core/Auth/SharedAccessSignatureHelper.cs#L422

Comment: If I may make a suggestion: May I suggest that you try and understand how authorization header is computed. It is extremely well documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services. My concern is that if you don't understand that, you would end up asking question for each and every REST API operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Get blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob) API

```
https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob
```

the **canonicalizedResource** should be `$"/{storageAccount}/{containerName}/{blobName}` **not**

```
$"/{storageAccount}/{containerName}/{filename}\ncomp:metadata\nrestype:container\ntimeout:20";
```

Please have a try to use the following demo code to download the blob. It works correctly on my side.

```
 var account = "storageAccount";
 var accountKey = "account key";
 var container = "container name";
 var blobName = "blob name";
 var apiVersion = "2015-12-11";
 var blobUrl = $"https://{account}.blob.core.windows.net/{container}/{blobName}";
 var method = "GET";
 var now = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R");
 var canonicalizedHeaders = $"x-ms-date:{now}\nx-ms-version:{apiVersion }";
 var canonicalizedResource = $"/{account}/{container}/{blobName}";
 var stringToSign = $"{method}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{canonicalizedHeaders}\n{canonicalizedResource}";
 var auth = CreateAuthString(account, stringToSign, accountKey);

 Uri uri = new Uri(blobUrl);
 HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-date", now);
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-ms-version", "2015-12-11");
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", auth);
 HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
 var status = response.IsSuccessStatusCode;



 private static string CreateAuthString(string blobStorageAccount, string signStr, string blobStorageAccessKey)
   {
            string signature;
            byte[] unicodeKey = Convert.FromBase64String(blobStorageAccessKey);
            using (HMACSHA256 hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256(unicodeKey))
            {
                byte[] dataToHmac = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signStr);
                signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
            }

            var authorizationHeader = String.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "{0} {1}:{2}",
                "SharedKey",
                blobStorageAccount,
                signature);

            return authorizationHeader;
      }
```

[image]